# Live compiler checks when developing and CTRL clicks in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, click, ctrl

I'm working from home and can't reach the server where my `Resharper` license is hosted, so `Resharper` is not working at the moment.

Without `Resharper` I don't see any develepment time compiler checks. So when I type

```
var test = new NonExistentClass();
```

I am not seeing any warning until I build the project. I assume this can be configured somewhere, but I can't find it.

Secondly, I am really missing the ability to CTRL + click method calls, variables and class names to jump directly to their declarations. Is this something Visual Studio 2010 is not capable of? I use this a lot and I must say I haven't seen a IDE that *can't* do this before, so I am hoping this also can be configured somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable live error checking by checking Tools, Options, Text Editor, C#, Advanced, Show live semantic errors.

You can enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - `MemberName` navigation by installing the Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: Productivity Power Tools is a must have extension, I cant rate it high enough (and it works well with resharper too)

Comment: I installed the Producticity Tools. They are quite allright. I like the improved search function. However, while the Productivity Power Tools allow me to CTRL + click method names and class names, it often brings me to the declaration of the method in an interface. Resharper also does this, but with Reshaper I can use CTRL+ALT+B to go to the implementation. I *think* Productivity Power Tools doesn't offer this, or does it? Also, PPT is not giving me code completion or CTRL+click behaviour in ascx files.